# Route traffic from certain site/url to a number of hand-picked nodes in a load balanced environment

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I inherited a loadbalancer (mod_proxy) setup consisting of 5 nodes.

The setup serves a number of 6 sites (site1, site2 etc, with shared disk space) and would like to know if there is a way to route traffic to only 2 of the nodes, namely 4 and 5 based on the **site/url requested**.

For example, what configuration do I have to include to mod_proxy config to only route traffic destined to say site3 (for example, www.site2.com/profile) to only nodes 4 and 5?

Have you ever done something similar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a Layer7 Load Balancer? So as below

site.com/Page1 = Server1/2
site.com/Page2 = Server3/4

Something like that? If so, please refer to the below link

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html